# Exact Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the DE: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{x+2y+1}{2x+4y-1}$$

So, this is an exact equation, but we aren't given an initial condition. I'm stuck at $\phi(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2} +2xy + 2y^2 - y = c$ since we can't solve for $c$. Also, are they asking us to solve for $y$ when they say "Solve the DE"?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz7ZB.png)

Comment: This is not an exact equation

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am always confused by such type of (empty) questions. So here is my possible answer: because.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

this is solution of exact differential equation

Comment: thank you, I don't forget that

Answer (score -1):

Recognise that we can transform the equation with $v=x+2y$, to yield
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=1 + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x},\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{v+1}{2v-1}.
$$
rearranging and combining the terms to obtain a single equation for $v$ you should arrive at
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{4v+1}{2v-1}.
$$

The solution to the above equation is:
$$
\frac{4v+1}{8} - \frac{3}{8}\mathrm{ln}\left(4v+1\right) = x + C_{1}.
$$
Now you can transform back to the original variables to and collect the constants i.e. terms independent of x and y into $C_{1}$ to arrive at the answer being $\mathbf{b}$ in the posted photo.